Is it possible to load wi-fi settings from the browser on mobile?
Not sure if this is the right question to ask, but the behavior I'm trying to get is making a QR code that has my Wi-Fi password so people can get on the Wi-Fi just by scanning, but also allow the Wi-Fi settings to change in the future (e.g. if I change it when I move to a new place).
If I use the Wi-Fi protocol in QR code it'll look something like this: WIFI:T:WPA;S:WIFINAME;P:PASSWORD;H:;;
Which isn't something I can change after the fact. I could have it point to a URL, but it doesn't seem like JS has the ability to load the Wi-Fi (I guess low-tech solution would be to just have the password there and people can copy-paste it, but then there would be a publicly accessible website with my Wi-Fi login details). Actually I guess even if the JS could directly load the Wi-Fi password that would mean I'm exposing the password to the internet...
So I guess the actual question here is: Is there a way to abstract the Wi-Fi part of a QR code such that it can change in the future, without exposing it publicly, and allowing users to load it automatically without needing to copy the password manually? Or is this just not possible and I have to live with generating a new QR code for a new Wi-Fi password?

I'm pretty sure the browser can't change wifi settings by itself. But you may be able to use a custom protocol that runs an app that does this.

doesn't sound doable. Beside, what's so bad  about generating new QR code?

Yeah I figured. Generating the QR code itself isn't the issue, I want to then take the QR code and use a controlnet model to generate a prettier image that still scans as a QR code and then frame it. I figured this might be annoying to do again in case the network settings ever change, but oh well.
